# Create a menu like on youtube in android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to make a menu like on youtube account fragment in my app. When I search about menus I just get answers "How to make a ActionBar Menu". Do you know what kind of element this is and how I can create this kind of menu?

[image]

Comment: Toolbar+TabLayout, FloatingActionButton, RecyclerView, a few ImageView, a few Spinner... What part exactly are you having issues creating?

Comment: I'm having trubble to do all of this. I'm a beginner in Android Studio and I have to read a lot of tutorials and ask questions here. The best would be a tutorial or a word I can look for how to do this

Comment: Well, start at the top. Try to get a TabLayout working

Comment: It's fine you're a beginner, but you're asking a really broad question with no attempts, and it's unlikely someone will just hand you the entire Activity + Fragment layout

Comment: @cricket_007 I know... I'm trying all myself before asking here and I'm searching a lot about my problems. I also think it's very unlikely to ask other people for help...

Comment: @cricket_007 By the way I don't mean the tablayout at the top. I've searched about it and its the wrong thing. I mean the List with "Verlauf" etc.

Comment: That's just a ListView or RecyclerView

Comment: Really? Do you know a good tutorial for this? :) I'll post my answer here how to do this

Comment: Any tutorial that shows how to define an Adapter and uses either one of those classes is as good as any

Comment: @cricket_007 Okay mate, I'll search for this and post my solution here :) Just takte a look in a couple of hours

Comment: Check this link: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview it's a nice tutorial for how to use a recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stuff you've highlighted is probably either a ListView or RecyclerView that has a good material design.

**Here is the Google documentation on RecyclerView's:**
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

**And here is an example tutorial I have previously followed:**
http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/11/android-recyclerview-example.html?m=1

Comment: What is better? A RecyclerView or a ListView?

Comment: Depends, RecyclerView was intended to phase out ListView. However, both work fine. For lists with multiple views, like what you're asking above, I recommend the RecyclerView despite it being a bit more complicated. Thankfully there are lots of tutorial's online!

Comment: Thanks for your choice! I'll try my best

Comment: Look at this http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/ a great tutorial I think :) I'll try this now!

Comment: Looks good, similar to the one I use. if I've answered you're question, it's good to mark it as solved^