# Got an error in my RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my RecyclerView (Relating to my question here: [Create a menu like on youtube in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721612/create-a-menu-like-on-youtube-in-android-studio)). I've asked a question about making an options menu like on youtube. I've done all of the steps from this tutorial here: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

When I start my app in debuggin mode I'm getting an error:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Here is my Fragment class:

```js
package de.myfirstapp.app;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link SettingsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link SettingsFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {
    // Variables
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    // Variables for Recycler View
    private List<Settings> settingList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SettingsAdapter sAdapter;

    public SettingsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    //Change the title in action bar
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        String titleString = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_navigation_drawer_settings);
        // Set title bar
        ((NavigationDrawerActivity) getActivity())
                .setActionBarTitle(titleString);
    }

    public static SettingsFragment newInstance() {
        SettingsFragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view  =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.settings_recycler_view);

        sAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(settingList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager sLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(sLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(sAdapter);

        prepareSettingsData();

        return view;
    }

    private void prepareSettingsData() {
        // Create new setting
        Settings setting = new Settings("Abmelden");
        settingList.add(setting);

        // Notify data changes
        sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) getActivity();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

My SettingsAdapter.class:

```js
package de.myfirstapp.app;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Johannes on 19.01.2017.
 */

public class SettingsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SettingsAdapter.MySettingHolder> {

    private List<Settings> settingList;

    public class MySettingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView settingTitle;

        public MySettingHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            settingTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.settingTitle);
        }
    }

    public SettingsAdapter (List<Settings> settingList) {
        this.settingList = settingList;
    }

    @Override
    public MySettingHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, parent, false);

        return new MySettingHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MySettingHolder holder, int position) {
        Settings setting = settingList.get(position);
        holder.settingTitle.setText(setting.getSettingTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return settingList.size();
    }

}
```

When you need the other classes too like the the xml you can leave a comment but I don't want to overload the question with unnecessary informations.

Comment: That warning you will get only when the adapter is not set to recyclerView.

Comment: Okay but I attached it I think

Comment: use `prepareSettingsData();` before `sAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(settingList);`

Comment: why you are setting an empty adapter? try to first init your list and then setting it to your adapter

Comment: @VygintasB not working

Answer (score 1):

That was my bad in previous answer,

Please try doing this,

Try to move this code into `onStart()` method,

```
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager sLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(sLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(sAdapter);
```

Comment: I'll try :) what is with the `sAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(settingList);`

Comment: As @Pravin mentioned it is because your list is empty when you are trying to set the adapter so first try to retrieve the data (call   `prepareSettingsData();`)  and then try to attach the adapter.

Comment: I've did like you said. I'm getting the entry "Abmelden" in the list like before but the error is displayed again

Comment: I've seperated the recylcer layout from the main layout into its own layout xml. It's working no. Don't know why :D

Comment: a layout file containing only RecyclerView and then you included that file into your fragment_settings.xml ?

Comment: @Darshand Soni the fragment_settings.xml includes the RecyclerView ands I've sperated the items in its own xml

Comment: I need help with the RecyclerView. I have two TextView elements and sometimes two are filled and the other time just one. The problem is that when the second TextView is empty it is not completely gone (just without text). How can I remove this empty TextView?

Comment: You can put the condition as if the TextView is empty hide it from the layout using textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: And on which point of my code should I do this? I think I have to make a TextView object and ask if its empty or not? Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133551/discussion-between-darshan-soni-and-itsodi1).

Answer (score 1):

Its because your settingList is empty use below code

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view  =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.settings_recycler_view);
        prepareSettingsData();
        sAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(settingList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager sLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(sLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(sAdapter);



        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void de.myfirstapp.app.SettingsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference

Comment: I've seperated the recylcer layout from the main layout into its own layout xml. It's working no. Don't know why :D